# Git allowing me to switch branches without committing changes

Tags: git

I am just learning Git, going through a tutorial. I am in branch seo_title and I have uncommitted changes to file mission.html. I did `git checkout master` expecting to get the warning about Changes not staged for commit, no changes added, etc, however instead it went ahead and switched branches with the message:

```
M       mission.html
Switched to branch 'master'
```

Then when I did `git diff mission.html` it showed me that the working directory still contains the changes I made while I had the other branch checked out. 
What am I missing?
For what it's worth, I am using Git Bash on Windows.

EDIT: the changes to mission.html have not been added to staging index either.

EDIT 2: I thought the top voted answer was correct, but upon further investigation it doesn't match the behavior I am seeing. Here is a fuller description of what I am doing:

```
top_directory(master) > git branch new_branch_1
top_directory(master) > git branch new_branch_2
top_directory(master) > git checkout new_branch_1
```

(open notepad++ and modify resources.html, save)

```
top_directory(master) > git status
# On branch new_branch_1
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in wo
#
#       modified:   resources.html
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit
top_directory(new_branch_1) > git checkout new_branch_2
```

This is where I expect git to object and tell me to stash or commit since new_branch_1 and new_branch_2 have different versions of resources.html, but it just switches to the new branch without a warning and it brings the uncommitted changes along:

```
M       resources.html
Switched to branch 'new_branch_2'
top_directory(new_branch_2) > git status
# On branch new_branch_2
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       modified:   resources.html
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Is there a mode or a setting that would make it behave this way instead of warning? Or am I still misunderstanding the scenario?

EDIT 3: I get it now. The top rated answer was right, see my last comment on that answer.

Comment: What is the question? Yes, git allows to checkout other branch. This is quite useful. If by mistake if you edited the file from the wrong branch, you can checkout the correct branch and commit there.

Comment: The thing I am confused about is: I thought checkout would try to update the working directory to match the new branch, and, when it found uncommitted changes (which would be lost when the working directory is updated) that it would abort the checkout. At least that is what the tutorial indicated (and I witnessed) in an earlier lesson

Comment: It's probably because you don't have any commit after the master branch. So, all your branches point to the same commit object. When you check out from a different branch, you actually check out from the same commit with current branch.

Comment: I think this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/16113552/46249 says it very well: "Git will let you checkout other branches (or tags or SHA1 hashes) as long as the commit you're changing your work-tree to does NOT clobber your local uncommitted changes."

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The different behaviour you saw from the last time you tried to switch branches with local changes and now is due to different file changes.

So, let's say we have a branch called 'readme' where you have committed some changes to a file, let's say README.md.

Now, you have switched back to master. You do some work on other files (not README.md). Now you have local changes. If you try to switch back to the 'readme' branch without committing your changes, it will let you. Why? Because switching to the 'readme' branch won't override any of your local changes.

If, however you make a modification to the README.md file on the master branch, then when you try to do a

```
git checkout readme
```

you will encounter

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout: README.md
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches.
```

because you have changes to README.md that would require a merge.

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12044758/1048479) might be of some help as well.

Comment: What you describe is what I expect, but not what I am seeing. I am adding further description in the question

Comment: Nevermind. I reread again and now it makes sense. Now I am thinking of it like this: this warning is like a conflict warning during merging except it occurs when you have UNcommitted changes in your branch and when you are switching branches, not committing. If a commit-merge would not create a conflict, then it will allow you to switch branches without committing/stashing.

Comment: What good is this behavior? Would be more friendly if it's rejected by default. It is possible to do this as a setting?

Comment: @huggie Why should git do this? You have some files on dev branch. If they are staged, then git compares two versions and gives you warning if there are conflicts. Well this is natural, but if your files are not staged, that means git should not care about them. What else do you expect? To delete unstaged files? If you need to delete temporarily, stash them. If you don't need them at all, delete them, but don't expect git to ask you for deleting them , cause it's your job to decide about your (unstaged) changes.

Answer (score 16):

This is the normal behavior.  If you don't want the modified files on your newly checked out branch, then stash them.  Like this.

```
# on branch dev
$ git stash
$ git checkout master

# do stuff on master

# back to dev
$ git checkout dev
$ git stash pop
```

Answer (score 2):

Git will let you checkout other branches (or tags or SHA1 hashes) as long as the commit you're changing your work-tree to does **NOT** clobber your local uncommitted changes.

In your case the branch `master`'s work-tree would have had the same version of `missing.html` as that currently exists in the tip of your current branch you were switching from. Git does not need to touch the working copy (for `missing.html` at least) when changing branches here, and hence lets you keep your local modifications.

If you indeed tried to `checkout` a commit where there was a different version of `missing.html` in the work-tree (than the one committed in your current branch), git would show an error message similar to this:

```
$ git checkout some-other-branch
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
        missing.html
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches.
Aborting
```

Answer (score 0):

[Git - the stupid content tracker](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/README). It just operates with working tree snapshots. The main requirement - you should be able to reconstruct working tree. It does update of course. But if the modified file is the same in both branches - why not to allow switch? If you done it by mistake, you could switch back reconstructing previous state, no big deal. But if the file is differ in the branches, you need merge content, that's why it insists to commit changes, otherwise it will be impossible to go back.

Answer (score 0):

this is obvious, if you change a file which is not changed in the branch you want to checkout into, because the syntactic of checkout is to bring all the index and working directory to your new branch, you will have them appeared in your new branch. While if there r conflicts, chances r u need to merge those files, which means once after merge, if you checkout back to your old branch then it is already the merged version not your previous one, you lose it. As a result, to make sure you keep the old change it won't let you do that.