# child branch and parent branch synching themselves

Tags: git, github, version-control, git-flow

There is a feature branch A which was cut out of B using git-flow.

There is no history of what all commands were run in between.

But now any modification done to a file in A shows up in B too.

```
git checkout feature/A
echo "test" >> existing_file.txt
git status
M   existing_file.txt
git checkout develop
git status
M   existing_file.txt
```

Can anybody help me understand what's happening here? That's happening with any new branch I create out of B.

I have finished branch A merging it with B and deleted A. The behavior still follows with other newly created branches out of B.

Comment: tagging @mu-無 for quick help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

git-flow or not, a regular [`git checkout`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout) will not modify the files being modified if the files are the same between the two branches:

> Local modifications to the files in the working tree are kept, so that they can be committed to the `<branch>`.

See also "[Git allowing me to switch branches without committing changes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16113523/6309)".